# pypdf2 is not defined

Tags: python, pypdf

new to python 3.7 version. 
Trying to use `pypdf2` but I have an error that I can't fix by myself:

my comand:

```
pdfFile2 = open(r"C:\Users\Luca\Desktop\python\tutorial\doc2.pdf", "wb")  # w=write, r=read, b=binary
writer1 = pyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
```

The error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Luca/Desktop/python/tutorial/tutorial.py", line 8, in <module>
    writer1 = pyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()`

`NameError: name 'pyPDF2' is not defined`

I have installed the `pypdf2` library but I cant go on, how can I fix this?

Comment: Did you import the library? `import PyPDF2` at the top of the file? I also don't think you're using the library correctly - check out a [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-work-with-pdf-documents-using-python--cms-25726)

Comment: yes i did usign this line imjport pypdf2

Comment: Case matters. `imjport pypdf2` is not the same as `import PyPDF2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1:
PyPDF2 is a pure Python package, so you can install it using pip (assuming pip is in your system’s path):

> python -m pip install pypdf2

Step 2:
Once you install that packages.
You can import the specific packages like *PdfFileReader* & *PdfFileWriter* from that library.

> from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

Step 3:
 Finally, you can instantized that module object directly

# For Reader

> reader=**PdfFileReader**(open("fpath",'rb'))

# For Write

> writer=**PdfFileWriter**()
>    outfp=open("outpath",'wb')
>   writer.write(outfp)

Doc: https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileWriter.html

Answer (score 1):

This is happening most likely because your example uses `pyPDF2` (small `p`) instead of `PyPDF2`(capital `P`) in the second line of your code.